# Advertisement in flask microblog

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have code of microblog in flask. It described in official tutorial

https://flask-blogging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#blog-page

I tried to open and run it

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, redirect
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from flask_login import UserMixin, LoginManager, login_user, logout_user
from flask_blogging import SQLAStorage, BloggingEngine
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

    
app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
storage = SQLAStorage(db=db)
db.create_all()
    
blogging_engine = BloggingEngine()

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret"  # for WTF-forms and login
app.config["BLOGGING_URL_PREFIX"] = "/blog"
app.config["BLOGGING_DISQUS_SITENAME"] = "test"
app.config["BLOGGING_SITENAME"] = "My Site"
app.config["BLOGGING_KEYWORDS"] = ["blog", "meta", "keywords"]
app.config["FILEUPLOAD_IMG_FOLDER"] = "fileupload"
app.config["FILEUPLOAD_PREFIX"] = "/fileupload"
app.config["FILEUPLOAD_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS"] = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"]

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///blog.db")
meta = MetaData()
sql_storage = SQLAStorage(engine, metadata=meta)
blog_engine = BloggingEngine(app, sql_storage)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
meta.create_all(bind=engine)


class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.id = user_id

    def get_name(self):
        return "Paul Dirac"  # typically the user's name

@login_manager.user_loader
@blog_engine.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User(user_id)

index_template = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="/logout/"> Logout </a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="/login/"> Login </a>
        {% endif %}
        &nbsp&nbsp<a href="/blog/"> Blog </a>
        &nbsp&nbsp<a href="/blog/sitemap.xml">Sitemap</a>
        &nbsp&nbsp<a href="/blog/feeds/all.atom.xml">ATOM</a>
        &nbsp&nbsp<a href="/fileupload/">FileUpload</a>
    </body>
</html>
"""

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template_string(index_template)

   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

It goes good but it show a problem. The code shows me advertisement from google. Tell me please how should I delete advertisement?

Comment: please provide picture of it.

Comment: Make sure that you have no addons or something similar injecting ads into your browser

Comment: Try in a different browser. Based on your code, it seems there should be no Google ad, at least in the index page ("/").

Comment: I tried in different browsers. All of them consists of advertisment

Answer (score 0):

Set blogging_disqus_sitename variable to None, this completely hides Disqus form and ads.

```
app.config["BLOGGING_DISQUS_SITENAME"] = None
```